# Liquibase Add Unique Constraint During Table Creation

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I want to add a unique constraint to my table during it's creation.
I thought something like this would work but it seems to just do nothing.

```
<createTable tableName="MY_TABLE">
   <column name="MY_TABLE_ID" type="SMALLINT" autoIncrement="true">
      <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
   </column>
   <column name="TABLE_FIELD" type="SMALLINT">
      <constraints nullable="false" uniqueConstraintName="TABLE_FIELD_ix1"/>
   </column>
   <column name="TABLE_FIELD_TWO" type="SMALLINT">
      <constraints nullable="false" uniqueConstraintName="TABLE_FIELD_ix1"/>
   </column>
</createTable>
```

I know I can use the addUniqueConstraint tag (and have successfully used it) after I create the table but I wanted to know if that was avoidable.

Basically I want to do this but during the create table portion

```
<addUniqueConstraint tableName="MY_TABLE"
                     columnNames="TABLE_FIELD, TABLE_FIELD_TWO"
                     constraintName="TABLE_FIELD_ix1"/>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding `unique="true"` to `<constraints>`.

```
    <createTable tableName="MY_TABLE">
       <column name="MY_TABLE_ID" type="SMALLINT" autoIncrement="true">
          <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
       </column>
       <column name="TABLE_FIELD" type="SMALLINT">
          <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" uniqueConstraintName="TABLE_FIELD_ix1"/>
       </column>
       <column name="TABLE_FIELD_TWO" type="SMALLINT">
          <constraints nullable="false" unique="true" uniqueConstraintName="TABLE_FIELD_ix2"/>
       </column>
    </createTable>
```

This creates two separate unique constraints, one on each of the two fields. It does not create a unique constraint for the set of `(TABLE_FIELD, TABLE_FIELD_TWO)`.

Comment: The 'unique' field means the column itself needs every value in it to be unique I thought? Instead of seeing if the 3 columns together are a unique set.

Comment: Yes, each value in the column needs to be unique. The same is done by `addUniqueConstraint`. Is this not was you want to do?

Comment: It says "Constraint "TABLE_FIELD_IX1" already exists" when I put unique on all of them. Odd it didn't say that until I put that field on them all.

Comment: The goal is to make the set made by those columns unique in the database.

Comment: Oh, I missed it in your code. You can't have two unique constraints with the same name. Names should be unique too. I've updated the attached code

Comment: If the goal is to make the set made by those two columns unique in the database, then I guess you'll have to use `addUniqueConstraint` tag for it.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to find a way to do that during the create table portion. Just thought I might be missing something but I think I'll just use the addUniqueConstraint and be content =)